# CORS error while trying to post data with Axios on AWS REST API configuration using a node.js Lambda function

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I'm posting data to a DynamoDB table with axios in a React front-end.
The API is set up through a serverless configuration with an API Gateway and Lambda on AWS.

While the request goes through and I see the added item on the database I still get a CORS error https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7yMG.jpg

This is the axios method:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const sendItemToDB = async (_data) => {
    if (!_data) { return };
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_QUERY_API,
            data: _data,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            },
        });
        console.log("data returned from api", res);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error sending File to db: ");
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

And the API method on Lambda:

```js
const createRecord = async (event) => {
    const response = { statusCode: 200 };

    try {
        const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
        const params = {
            TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME,
            Item: marshall(body || {}),
        };
        const createResult = await db.send(new PutItemCommand(params));
        response.body = JSON.stringify({
            message: "Successfully created record.",
            createResult,
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        response.statusCode = 500;
        response.body = JSON.stringify({
            message: "Failed to create record.",
            errorMsg: e.message,
            errorStack: e.stack,
        });
    }

    return response;
};
```

I based this configuration on this tutorial : https://github.com/jacksonyuan-yt/dynamodb-crud-api-gateway

Answer (score 3):

I solved this following amazon documentation and reconfiguring the serveless deployment yml.
Serverless documentation on api gateway and lambda proxy integration [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#lambda-proxy-integration)

Adding the missing headers to all lambda functions was essential.

```js
const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
    };
```

Also testing that OPTIONS is working for the preflight:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-test-cors.html

Answer (score 1):

Just as Stavros noticed, the problem is that this is not [a simple cross-origin POST method request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) (because it contains custom headers), so you need to tweak **CORS settings** of **AWS API Gateway** by adding

- "POST, GET & OPTIONS" for Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- "content-type" for Access-Control-Allow-Headers

You can do it through console like this

[image]

You also might need to add those headers in lambda like this
[image]
and it will work.